# right and left cosets of $D_4$

Tags: linear-algebra

i have  $ D_4= (i, d_1, d_1^2,d_1^3, s_1, d_1^2 \circ s_1, d_1 \circ s_1 , d_1^3 \circ s_1)$

with subgroups
$H_1={i} , H_2=(1,d_1^2), H_3=(1,s_1) , H_4 =(1, d_1 \circ s_1), H_5= (1, d_1^2 \circ s_1) , H_6= (1,d_1^3 \circ s_1) , H_7= (1,d_1,d_1^2,d_1^3) ,H_8=(1,d_1^2, s_1,d_1^2 \circ s_1) ,H_9=(1,d_1^2, d_1 \circ s_1, d_1^3 \circ s_1)$

now i have to determine which of them are normal subgroups. 
So i have to determine the rght and left cosets. Can you please give me with my Task an example how determine those? i dont really understand the defintion.

Comment: Do you know conjugacy classes? If you know that then. Determining the normal subgroups becomes easier

Comment: By the way $D_{4}$has eight element, I think there is a typo.

Comment: no we didnt do cnjugacy classes...i think i am supposted to determine all by Hand unfortunatly. and yes, there is a typo :0

Comment: What are you exactly asking then how to compute a left or a right coset?

Comment: yes, just an example, so i can also understand th Definition :)

Comment: Your question is not about linear algebra.  Use "abstract-algebra" and/or "group-theory" tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have the following relations: am denoting $d_{1}$ by $r$ and $s_{1}$ by $s$.
So, $r^{4}=1=s^{2}$, $sr=r^{-1}s$.

Now , Let me tell you for your verification that $H_{2}$ and $H_{7}$ are the only normal subgroups. Others are not. $H_{2}$ is the center of the group.(Verify!). $H_{7}$ is index two subgroup and hence normal( A common result!).

Let us take $H_{3}=\{\ 1, s \}\ $. By definition a left coset of $H$ in $G$, $aH= \{\ ah| h \in H \}\ $ for $a\in G$.

Let us compute $rH_{3}=\{\ r.1, r.s \}\ $ and $H_{3}r=\{\ 1.r, s.r \}\ $. But you see $rs$ and $sr$ are not equal. $sr=r^{3}s \neq rs$. Hence , $rH_{3} \neq H_{3}r$. Hence $H_{3}$ is not normal, because by definition of normal subgroup , a subgroup $H$ in $G$ is normal if $aH=Ha$ for every $a \in G$.

You can do the others similarly.

Comment: thank you a lot, that helped to clear everything :)